# Oracle TO_DATE() function - what is the universal version?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, ansi-sql

What is the universal version of Oracle SQL function `TO_DATE()` or `TO_TIMESTAMP()`?

Simple table for example:

```
CREATE TABLE  SAMPLE
    (
        TRUE_DATE DATE,
        CHAR_DATE VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
    );
```

When using same TO_DATE() function for writing date in DATE and VARCHAR field like this

```
INSERT INTO SAMPLE
(TRUE_DATE, CHAR_DATE)
VALUES
(TO_DATE('1990-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('1990-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

in Oracle it will work without error. How can I write something similar, with same behavior, to work on all database systems?

Comment: There is no universal version,but you can write different queries for different databases and check for the db flavor in the application and use the correct query for that particular db.Not what you were looking for,I know.

Comment: @Mihai: there is a "universal" version - the one that is defined by the SQL standard. Buf whether or not all DBMS support that is another question

Comment: `TO_DATE` returns a DATE. `TO_TIMESTAMP` returns a TIMESTAMP. These are different data types altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "universal" version would be the date and timestamp literal format as defined by the SQL standard: `date '2014-09-20'` or `timestamp '2014-09-20 22:43:03'`

But not all DBMS support that - but more DBMS support ANSI literals than `to_date()`